# A method that activates when I equip armor

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm making a mod for Minecraft and right now I'm working on making enchantments that give you special potion effects. I've been working on a Health Boost enchantment and started by activating the effect every update. When you do that, it makes a hurt cam effect every update, so I switched to every equipment change. That worked better, but every time I had more then an extra half-heart and switched/dropped an item it made the hurt-cam again. I wanted to use some kind of an `onArmorEquip` event but I didn't see an option for one. I'm working on Eclipse for Minecraft 1.12.2, anybody have suggestions? This is my code:

```
@SubscribeEvent
public static void enchantTankFunction(LivingEquipmentChangeEvent event)
{
    Object player = event.getEntityLiving();
    if(player instanceof EntityLivingBase)
    {
        EntityLivingBase entityPlayer = (EntityLivingBase)player;
        int levelFeet = EnchantmentHelper.getEnchantmentLevel(ENCHANT_TANK, entityPlayer.getItemStackFromSlot(EntityEquipmentSlot.FEET));
        int levelLegs = EnchantmentHelper.getEnchantmentLevel(ENCHANT_TANK, entityPlayer.getItemStackFromSlot(EntityEquipmentSlot.LEGS));
        int levelChest = EnchantmentHelper.getEnchantmentLevel(ENCHANT_TANK, entityPlayer.getItemStackFromSlot(EntityEquipmentSlot.CHEST));
        int levelHead = EnchantmentHelper.getEnchantmentLevel(ENCHANT_TANK, entityPlayer.getItemStackFromSlot(EntityEquipmentSlot.HEAD));
        if(!entityPlayer.getEntityWorld().isRemote && (levelFeet > 0 || levelLegs > 0 || levelChest > 0 || levelHead > 0))
        {
            entityPlayer.removePotionEffect(MobEffects.HEALTH_BOOST);
            entityPlayer.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(MobEffects.HEALTH_BOOST, (24 * 60 * 60 * 20), (levelFeet) + (levelLegs) + (levelChest) + (levelHead) - 1, false, false));
        }
        else
        {
            entityPlayer.removePotionEffect(MobEffects.HEALTH_BOOST);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version is this for? It doesn't look like 1.15.

Comment: TheKingElessar this is for 1.12.2 since I mostly play that version. Sorry, editing that into the original post right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do. You can get which equipment slot was changed, then the item that was changed. This is untested, but something similar to this should work.

This checks that the entity is a player and that the equipment change takes place in an armor slot (you probably only need help with this part).

```
@SubscribeEvent
public static void enchantSaturationFunction(LivingEquipmentChangeEvent event)
{
    if (event.getEntityLiving() instanceof EntityPlayer) // Remove this if you want other mobs to get the benefits
    {
        EntityEquipmentSlot slotChanged = event.getSlot();
        if (slotChanged.getSlotIndex() > 0 && slotChanged.getSlotIndex() < 5) // Check out the class EntityEquipmentSlot
        {
```

And then, to finish it off, this gets the `ItemStack` of the new armor and checks the enchantments. I stole some code from `ItemStack::getTooltip`.

```
            ItemStack previousArmorPiece = event.getFrom();
            ItemStack newArmorPiece = event.getTo();

            NBTTagList nbtTagList = newArmorPiece.getEnchantmentTagList();

            for (int k1 = 0; k1 < nbtTagList.tagCount(); ++k1)
            {
                NBTTagCompound nbttagcompound = nbtTagList.getCompoundTagAt(k1);
                int enchantmentID = nbttagcompound.getShort("id");
                int enchantmentLevel = nbttagcompound.getShort("lvl");
                Enchantment enchantment = Enchantment.getEnchantmentByID(enchantmentID);
                if (enchantment instanceof MY_ENCHANTMENT)
                {
                    // They equipped armor with the necessary enchantment, so do what you want.
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know how to use the bottom segment so I used mine. the problem was actually in the top one, so this really helped me.